# If $X_n \to X$ in probability and $E[X_n] < \infty$, is $E[X] < \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to prove that

> If $X_n \sim N(\mu_n, \sigma_n^2)$ converges to $X$ in probability, then $X$ is also normal, and the convergence is indeed in $L^2$.

by following the argument in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24362/convergence-in-probability-and-l-2-for-normal-random-variables and without using the fact that $X_n \to X$ in distribution and tightness of $X_n$.

I believe it boils down to say $E[X] := \mu < \infty$. If that's the case, I could consider the characteristic function of $X_n - \mu_n\sim N(0,\sigma_n^2)$, and show the limit $X-\mu$ has normal distribution $N(0,\sigma^2)$. Could anyone give me some hint on this?

Comment: For the question in the title, NO.  For your result, tIghtness of $(X_n)$ will be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 question.

**Question 1:**

If $X_n \to X$ in probability and $EX_n < \infty$, is $EX< \infty$?

No. Consider $\xi \sim Cauchy(1)$, $X = |\xi|$,  $X_n = X I_{|X|<n}$. Hence $EX_n < \infty$, $X_n \to X$ in probability and $EX = \infty$.

**Question 2:**

How to prove ..., and without  using the fact that $X_n \to X$ in distribution and tightness of $X_n$?

If  we don't have condition $X_n \to X$ then we can't derive any properties of $X$.

Answer (score 2):

Using characteristic functions we see that $e^{i\mu_n t} e^{-t^{2}\sigma_n^{2}/2} \to Ee^{itX}$ for all $t$. Take absolute values to see that $\sigma_n $ converges. Then note that convergence of $e^{i\mu_n t}$ for every $t$ implies convergence of $(\mu_n)$. Hence $Ee^{itX} =e^{i\mu t} e^{-t^{2}\sigma^{2}/2}$, so $X$ is normal.

Comment: Thank you! Your idea helps a lot! But I made a bad title, so I think it's more appropriate to give the "green check" to the other answer.  Thank you again!